# Need help moving HTML+CSS Tabs below the respective content pane

Tags: html, css, tabs

I use radiobuttons to create a simple tab-bar for a webpage, using only HTML and CSS.

This is the current code: http://jsfiddle.net/nypd81x9/1/

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
    <label for="tab1">Description</label>
    <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
      <p>content 1</p>
    </div>
  </li>

 <li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
    <label for="tab2">Specification</label>
    <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
      <p>content 2</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

How do I move the tabs *below* the content, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vq3R.png

Thank you in forward

Comment: What is your CSS. Please place HTML and CSS into a jsfiddle

Comment: There is CSS in the jsfiddle

Comment: So do you want the tabs below the content?

Comment: why don't you juste set the top of the : .tabs .tab-content to "top: -75px;" ??

Comment: @Andrew Yes that is the question

Comment: @ZakariaWahabi I would go for this option but this tab view is located inbetween other elements of my site which needs to be responsive for mobile design, therefore this wouldn't work for me

Comment: yes, but setting bottom to 0 work fine and absolute position is always depending on the parent object dom , i dont think this don't work for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just change the CSS `top: 53px;`to `bottom:0;`

**CSS**

```
.tabs .tab-content {
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px; // Here is the change
  left: 0;
  background: #E6E6E6;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nypd81x9/2/)**

Comment: Thank you a lot! I spent longer on this than I'm willing to admit haha